# How to detect invalid urls with urlfetch

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

I am fetching gravatar using the following method

```
def fetch_gravatar(email):
    incorrect_base_url = 'http://ww.grvatar.com/avatar/'
    correct_base_url = 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/'
    gravatar_url = correct_base_url + hashlib.md5(email).hexdigest() + '?'
    gravatar_url2 = incorrect_base_url + hashlib.md5(email).hexdigest() + '?'
    size = str(feconf.GRAVATAR_SIZE_PX)
    gravatar_url += urllib.urlencode({'d':'identicon', 's':size})
    result = urlfetch.fetch(gravatar_url, headers={'Content-Type': 'image/png'})
    if result.status_code == 200:
        encoded_body = base64.b64encode(result.content)
        print result.status_code
        return 'data:{};base64,{}'.format('image/png', encoded_body)
    else:
        print result.status_code
        return '/images/avatar/user_blue_72px.png'
```

No matter whether I call the `urlfetch` with `gravatar_url` or `gravatar_url2` it alway prints `result.status_code` to be 200. How do I check If my url is good or not?

Answer (score 1):

This url http://ww.grvatar.com/avatar/ returns a HTTP 302 (redirect). Most probably you need to set follow_redirect=False on your call to urlfetch[1](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/refdocs/google.appengine.api.urlfetch#google.appengine.api.urlfetch.fetch)